# forms.py can't validate proprely in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

```
def clean_name(self):
    valname = self.cleaned_data['name']
    # if len(valname) < 3:
    #     raise forms.ValidationError('name must be at least 3 characters')
    # return valname # return the value if no error

    if valname[0] == 'S':
        raise forms.ValidationError('name cannot contain the letter S')
    return valname  # return the value if no error
```

here I apply validation name that should start with **S** but when I enter a string that can't start with S so it will not give me Validation error.

Comment: *but when I enter a string that can't start with S so it will not give me Validation error.* So, are you intending to avoid strings that are not started with S? because the code you have provided is checking if the string is starting with S, if does, it will raise an exception/error, if not, it is ok an return the string itself. I think I might miss something.

Comment: Your validation is basically saying anything the letter "S" is in the beginning of a string, raise forms.ValidationError(""). isn't that what you want?

Comment: Maybe you want to check if the number "S" is in the valname? then it will be `if 'S' in valname:`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
def clean_name(self):
valname = self.cleaned_data['name']
# if len(valname) < 3:
#     raise forms.ValidationError('name must be at least 3 characters')
# return valname # return the value if no error

if 'S' in valname[0]:
    raise forms.ValidationError('name cannot contain the letter S')
return valname  # return the value if no error
```

If you want to see whether the string contains the letter S you should use **in** operator. Your code on the other hand is comparing two strings so it will only return true if the value is only the letter S. But if you want to see if the string starts with the letter S than you should use the **startswith** method like so:

```
def clean_name(self):
valname = self.cleaned_data['name']
# if len(valname) < 3:
#     raise forms.ValidationError('name must be at least 3 characters')
# return valname # return the value if no error

if valname[0].startswith("S") :
    raise forms.ValidationError('name cannot contain the letter S')
```

hope this helped :)